# Discrete Shading in Blender

Tags: shaders

I'm trying to shade objects in a very specific way.  What I'd like to do is make my shading only 3 distinct shades.  Similar to a comic book.  Rather than a gradient, there exists only a darkest, medium, and light.  Is there a capability to shade a spherical object in such a way that it only uses 3 or 4 distinct tones rather than a continuous gradient?

Comment: You can use a gradient (aka ColorRamp) and switch it to **Constant**, giving you only the used colors with sharp edges between them.

Comment: You've just described 'toon' shading, that might make a good search term for you. There's a very controllable version, perhaps more than you need, illustrated in [this series of videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpWI2rU8iF0)

Comment: Ah, thank you so much!  I'm very new to 3d graphics and there is so much to learn!  Thanks again!

Comment: Hey another question, is there a way to outline the contour of objects with black line?

Comment: There are several methods : try searching for [Inverted hull](https://www.blendernation.com/2020/02/28/daily-blender-tip-inverted-hull-toon-outline) method or "Freestyle render". If you don't find anything, don't hesitate to create a new question for it !